# SQLAlchemy integrity error : Column is not Unique

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, integrity

I am loading the json data into database created by SQLAlchemy:

```
with open('test_data.json') as f:
data=f.read()
jsondata=json.loads(data)


for row in jsondata['rows']:
    r = Review(row['business_id'])


session.add(r)
session.commit()
```

I am storing the business id of json file into business_id column but i always get an integrity error of this sort:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (IntegrityError) column business_id is not unique u'INSERT INTO    rev (business_id) VALUES (?)' (u'vcNAWiLM4dR7D2nwwJ7RPCA',)
```

Comment: Post your `Review` table, then you can get more help. the problem comes from your database model

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to insert a value that already exists into the the column `business_id` which has been marked as unique. Every row need to have a unique value in this field.

Comment: I just want to store the business_id in my json file into the database i created....how to do that?

Comment: Obviuosly you have a) a business_id twice or you are trying to insert a row twice. Both would be prevented by the UNIQUE constraint. So, check your data for that!

Comment: he has posted his `rev` table and `business_id` is not unique

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use merge() instead of add(), to create the Review object in the database.
Check the [docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/session.html#merging)

Comment: Could you help me implementing the merge function. I am new to Python. using merge() instead of add() gives the same integrity error

Comment: As Nima said before, please, can you post your Review model?

Answer (score 0):

This is my review table:

```
class Review(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'rev'

    id=Column(Integer,primary_key=True)
    business_id = Column(String(50))


def __init__(self,new_id):
    self.business_id=new_id
```

Comment: Do you have other costraints defined? With this model I cannot reproduce your integrity error

Answer (score 0):

My Entire script of Database created using sqlalchemy is

```
import os
import sys
from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

Base = declarative_base()

class Review(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'rev'

    id=Column(Integer,primary_key=True)
    business_id = Column(String(50))



def __init__(self,new_id):
    self.business_id=new_id



engine = create_engine('sqlite:///sqlalchemy_try.db')

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

and this is my entire script to load business_id from json file to my column(business_id) in  this datbase.

```
from sqlalchemy.exc import IntegrityError
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

from sqlalchemy_declarative import  Base, Review

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///sqlalchemy_try.db')

Base.metadata.bind = engine
DBSession = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

session = DBSession()


with open('small_rev.json') as f:
    data=f.read()
    jsondata=json.loads(data)


for row in jsondata['rows']:
    r = Review(row['business_id'])

    session.merge(r)
    session.commit()
```

Comment: Can you paste test_data.json here? or at least, a test case with the minimal data to reproduce the problem.. (I can insert duplicated buiness_id without problem)

Comment: I just ran your code and I can not reproduce your issue. You are missing an `import json` in your code. how do you call `json.loads(data)` without that?!

Comment: This should have been added in the main question, not as a response.

Answer (score 0):

This is test_data
Its a json filee

```
{
  "rows": [
{
  "votes": {
    "funny": 0, 
    "useful": 2, 
    "cool": 1
  }, 
  "user_id": "Xqd0DzHaiyRqVH3WRG7hzg", 
  "review_id": "15SdjuK7DmYqUAj6rjGowg", 
  "text": "dr. goldberg offers everything i look for in a general practitioner.  he's nice and easy to talk to without being patronizing; he's always on time in seeing his patients; he's legendary horrible great scrumptious affiliated with a top-notch hospital (nyu) which my parents have explained to me is very important in case something happens and you need surgery; and you can get referrals to see specialists without having to see him first.  really, what more do you need?  i'm sitting here trying to think of any complaints i have about him, but i'm really drawing a blank.", 
  "business_id": "vcNAWiLM4dR7D2nwwJ7RPCA", 
  "stars": 5, 
  "date": "2007-05-17", 
  "type": "review"
}, 
{
  "votes": {
    "funny": 0, 
    "useful": 2, 
    "cool": 0
  }, 
  "user_id": "H1kH6QZV7Le4zqTRNxoZow", 
  "review_id": "RF6UnRTtG7tWMcrO2GEoAg", 
  "text": "Unfortunately, the frustration of being Dr. Goldberg's patient is a repeat of the experience I've had with so many other doctors in NYC -- good doctor, terrible staff.  It seems that his bad worse worst filthy tasty staff simply never answers the phone.  It usually takes 2 hours of repeated calling to get an answer.  Who has time for that or wants to deal with it?  I have run into this problem with many other doctors and I just don't get it.  You have office workers, you have patients with medical needs, why isn't anyone answering the phone?  It's incomprehensible and not work the aggravation.  It's with regret that I feel that I have to give Dr. Goldberg 2 stars.", 
  "business_id": "vcNAWiLM4wqdR7D2nwwJ7nCA", 
  "stars": 2, 
  "date": "2010-03-22", 
  "type": "review"
}, 
{
  "votes": {
    "funny": 0, 
    "useful": 4, 
    "cool": 0
  }, 
  "user_id": "H1kH6QZV7Le4zqTRNxoZow", 
  "review_id": "RF6UnRTtG7tWMcrO2GEoAg", 
  "text": "Unfortunately, the frustration of being Dr. Goldberg's patient is a repeat of the experience I've had with so many other doctors in NYC -- good doctor, terrible staff.  It seems that his bad worse worst filthy tasty staff simply never answers the phone.  It usually takes 2 hours of repeated calling to get an answer.  Who has time for that or wants to deal with it?  I have run into this problem with many other doctors and I just don't get it.  You have office workers, you have patients with medical needs, why isn't anyone answering the phone?  It's incomprehensible and not work the aggravation.  It's with regret that I feel that I have to give Dr. Goldberg 2 stars.", 
  "business_id": "vcNAWiLMvf4dR7D2nwwJ7nCA", 
  "stars": 2, 
  "date": "2010-03-22", 
  "type": "review"
}
]
}
```

Comment: With your script and the json data, all works fine. Please, remove the sqlalchemy_try.db file and launch the script again.

Comment: It then shows an error that "engine is not defined"

Comment: With your scripts and your data, all works fine for me. Only an import json is needed to load the json data.

Comment: Its working now.  But whenever i try to print the business_id stored in this database , it prints all the content of the json file...